# When I open the website on mobile device it doesn't show the index.html but some wierd menu

Tags: javascript, ajax

When I visit the page via mobile device (phone) it shows the menu to choose from instead I want the page to load the index right away.

(If you will check it via phone you will get what I mean)

Link: [www.eufrazia.sk/sitex/](http://www.eufrazia.sk/sitex/)

I would like the page to be loaded here "www.eufrazia.sk/sitex/home" when visited via phone

I'm not sure if below code may help to understand, but I think this code has something to do with it.

```
(function($){
window.FJSCore =
{
        local:location.protocol == "file:",
        basepath:location.pathname.slice(0, location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
        defState:'',
        defStateMobileText:'Úvod',
        emptyNavigationText:'-- Sekcie --',
        ajaxFolder:"/ajax/",
        indexFile:'index.html',
        modules:{},
        mobileFolowLinks:false,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like media queries because the menu only appears when navigating with a Phone's user-agent and not when changing the browser window size.

I suggest trying to remove the device.js file from your `<head>` element in the index file and then see whether any errors are thrown. This should resolve the issue.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- REMOVE THIS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/device.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/core.js"></script><script src="js/history.js?redirect=true&amp;basepath=/sitex/" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/TMForm.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/randomLettersGenerator.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/spin.min.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/tmMultimediaGallery.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I tried it but this doesnt solve my problem, because when I delete device.js the whole structure of page when seen on mobile phone changes to the one which can be seen on desktops. 

I just want the page to load right away when I open it via phone - thus eliminating that one step which is choosing the category of "Úvod" - the place where I want the page to load